# What is wrong with this recursion in C#?

Tags: c#, recursion

I would like to write a simple recursion with replacing a method three times and after finished, get back how many times the function was run.

I execute a caller method which gives an another method via parameter by delegate and prints a simple message three times.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public delegate void funct(string msg);

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void funct(string msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }

        public static int caller(funct f, string msg, int max, int count = 0)
        {
            if (count < max)
            {
                funct(msg);
                caller(f, msg, max, ++count);
            }

            return count;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = caller(funct, "LOL", 3);
            //should return value 3, but returned with value 1

        }
    }
}
```

The returning value is always wrong, because I got back 1, instead of 3.

Comment: just put ref int count

Comment: return caller(f,msg,max,++count);  ... what's happening is it falls through the first recursion and returns to the calling function.. return it to itself, so it won't hit the first return until it is more than max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you don't pass back the value of count up the recursion chain.

```
public static int caller(funct f, string msg, int max, int count = 0)
{
    if (count < max)
    {
        fugg(msg);
        return caller(f, msg, max, ++count);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are not changing the value of `count` in each call to the function `caller`. So, for each time the function is called, it is simply going to return the current value of `count`, which at the end of the execution is just `count` plus one. In the very first call of `caller`, the value of count went from zero to one, and the subsequent recursive calls of `caller` will not affect the value of `count` anymore.

Perhaps you should rewrite `caller` as such:

```
    public static int caller(funct f, string msg, int max, int count = 0)
    {
        if (count < max)
        {
            funct(msg);
            count = caller(f, msg, max, count + 1);
        }

        return count;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass on the value of `count` to the recursve call to `caller`. This is a pass by value, so even if you change the value of `count` in the recursive call, the updated value is not passed back. You simply need to update the value of count in the caller before you return it:

```
    public static int caller(funct f, string msg, int max, int count = 0)
    {
        if (count < max)
        {
            funct(msg);
            count = caller(f, msg, max, ++count);
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at how your stack works:

```
Level 1:
Count gets initialized as 0;
Msgbox shows
Calls itself
    Level 2:
    Count gets passed in as 1;
    Msgbox shows
    Calls itself
        Level 3
        Count gets passed in as 2;
        Msgbox shows
        Calls itself
            Level 4
            Count gets passed in as 3;
            Count is too high;
            returns 3;
        Returns count (for its scope), which is 3
    Returns count (for its scope), which is 2
Returns count (for its scope), which is 1.
```

You've got two easy ways of fixing it.  One is to change the variable so that it's by reference.  But honestly, I prefer just returning the function's retVal back up the chain, like this:

```
    public static int caller(funct f, string msg, int max, int count = 0)
    {
        if (count < max)
        {
            funct(msg);
            return caller(f, msg, max, ++count);
        }

        return count;

    }
```